# How do I apply the indent rule in ESLint to styled components?

Tags: reactjs, configuration, eslint, indentation, styled-components

*(I'm new to this so please tell me if I need to add some more information to my question)*

I'm trying to add a rule to indent styled components like this:

```
const link = styled.a`
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
`;
```

I'm using this rule:

```
"indent": ["error", "tab"]
```

I thought that the rule didn't applied to styled components because it uses template literals, but then I also saw that you can add "ignoredNodes": ["TemplateLiteral > *"] to the rule. Which indicates that the rule should work with template literals? But in my case it doesn't..

Does someone have a solution to why my indentation doesn't work with template literals, or a suggestion to another solution on how to fix my indentation in styled component?

I'm using below versions:

```
"styled-components": "^5.2.1",
"eslint": "^7.23.0"
```

**UPDATE:**
I'm trying to solve this without Prettier.

Answer (score 1):

The configuration `"ignoredNodes": ["TemplateLiteral > *"]` does not work since the lines in the TemplateLiteral (in your example) are not the nodes of the Abstract Syntax Tree. You might paste your code snippet in [AST explorer](https://astexplorer.net/) to confirm.

As far as I know, linter has nothing to do with indenting string content and template literal content. To indent styled component, you should use a formatter, such as [Prettier](https://prettier.io/docs/en/comparison.html) instead. ESLint can format the code with Prettier, via the packages `eslint-plugin-prettier` and `eslint-config-prettier` (but still you have to install `prettier`).

And to indent your styled component, installing the above packages, creating `.prettierrc.json` file (with rules that does not conflict with ESLint), adding ESLint rules `"prettier/prettier": ["error", {}, { "usePrettierrc": true }]` is a good start.

Comment: Oh okay thank you! unfortunately we don't want to use Prettier and are trying to find another way to make this work..

Comment: did you find any solution ?